# Normal for WS2812B LED's to turn on immediately when powered?

Tags: ws2812b

Is it normal for all the LED's on a programmable LED strip to turn on as soon as power is applied?   I have 3 strips of WS28182B's, and they're all behaving exactly the same way - the 300 LED's all go to white color, full brightness the instant 5V is connected to the red and white wires.  The green data wire is left open, but grounding it makes no difference.  Neither does a 10uf capacitor across the power leads.  I'm now having an argument with the vendor who claims this is normal behavior.  From everything I've seen and tried in the past, this is not normal, and these are defective strips.   Does anyone have info to the contrary?

Comment: Can you still control them with a controller?

Comment: Reasonable question, but difficult answer.  My application never requires all 300 LED's to be simultaneously turned on, so my power supply isn't rated for that much current.  Thus, it current-limits as soon as I apply power to the string, which means I can't verify whether the LED's are controllable or not.  So, my question is really whether this LED behavior is sufficient proof that the string is defective, or is there a scenario where a properly functioning strip would default to fully-on at power up?

Comment: have you in the mean time found an answer to this? I struggle at the moment with the same problem :(

Comment: @Tobi I changed your question to a comment. You will be able to do that when you get slightly more reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is normal behavior, not all "magic" Leds are the same. They work the same but some of them will start white, this is feature, because You can test them without applying control signal.